# How to get value of NSBigMutableString

Tags: objective-c, macos

I have an array of float numbers that got calculated through a series of multiplication. One of the numbers in that array has went over the largest number float can handle. When I display all the numbers in an NSTextView using this method:

```
- (void)updateResultLabel:(NSArray<NSNumber *> *)results {
    NSMutableString *string = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:100];
    for (NSNumber *number in results) {
        [string appendFormat:@"%f\n", number.floatValue];
   }
    self.resultLabel.string = string;
}
```

I got `inf` for the number that overflows. I wants to make it displays a more user-friendly text. I tried typing this command in the debugger:

```
print string
```

When the breakpoint is on the `self.resultLabel.string = string;` line. It gives me this:

```
(NSBigMutableString *) $0 = 0x0000618000041ec0 class name = NSBigMutableString
```

I tried to use `[string isEqualToString:@"inf"]` that has no use. How do you check whether it has the inf string so I can change it to a more user-friendly string?

Comment: Are you working with iOS or OSX?  Your question is tagged [tag:ios], but you want to put your numbers in an `NSTextView`, which is only available on OS X.

Comment: @JAL Oh Sorry, I put in the wrong tag.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, I've edited your tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using `INFINITY` is a solution for this. 
example usage is

```
 float t = 1231231231889989899898232131231232312312.323132123123131231231231231231231321;
    if (t == INFINITY) {
        NSLog(@"inf it is");
    }
```

it is defined in `math.h` as

```
#define INFINITY    HUGE_VALF
```

in your case

```
for (NSNumber *number in results) {
        if(number.floatValue != INFINITY)
            [string appendFormat:@"%f\n", number.floatValue];
        else {
             //set the other text.
        }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try use method stringValue in NSValue for reduce array in string?

```
- (void)updateResultLabel:(NSArray<NSNumber *> *)results {
    NSMutableString *string = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:100];
    for (NSNumber *number in results) {
        [string appendFormat:@"%@\n", number.stringValue];
   }
    self.resultLabel.string = string;
}
```